# Read value for random generated child in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read all the values from my firebase database. My child values are randomly generated using

```
.push.getkey()
```

My database structure looks as below:
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzOFS.png)

Example: child -MFo2XLRF34Pez_xeVAT contains a Jobs object.

How can I get all the values of randomly generated child nodes ? Since i can't pass the values to `datasource.child()`since I don't know the name of the child.
I just want to save all the Jobs objects into an ArrayList but I can't access them.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Job class with getter and setter for the information you have at that node then to get the data you do this:

```
     DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobs");
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Jobs jobs = dataSnapshot.getValue(Jobs.class);
                jobsList.add(jobs);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I already have the Jobs class in my project. It does  not work like this since the value of the  child node is not a parameter for Jobs class - example: I should do a setter and getter for -MFo2XLRF34Pez_xeVAT parameter. Also I have already tried with the above code.

Comment: com.<packagename>  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -MFoYE90U6_38vTMS5wb found on class com<packagename>.Jobs you get an error like the above.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my `databasereference`. Instead of assigning `databasereference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobs")` i was using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` which was pointing to the root node. After that `dataSnapshot.getValue()` worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi, you mentioned setter and getter in Jobs class not in the database reference.

Comment: Well I thought I'm clear when I added the sample and having the reference already set up.